# Matlab displayFormula has a bug when using matrices?

Tags: matlab

```
displayFormula("c=b*a")
syms a
displayFormula("c=b*a", a, 6)
displayFormula("c=b*a", a, [[1 2];[3 4]])
d=[[1 2];[3 4]]
displayFormula("c=b*d")
```

Line 1 executes fine. Line 2 is needed to permit execution of line 3. Line 4 throws an error. Line 6 executes fine and displays the entire matrix. Line 6 successful execution, which is displaying the entire matrix, suggests displayFormula can take matrices as inputs. On the other hand, Line 4 error suggests that displayFormula cannot take matrices as inputs. Line 3 demonstrates that the verbose form of displayFormula can take Ints, Floats, Doubles as arguments.

I suspect that this is just a Matlab bug, or perhaps a feature that i would like which has not been implemented, but I also wonder if I am making a mistake.

Line 4 throws the following error:

```
Error using displayFormula
Inconsistency between sizes of second and third arguments.

Error in bugDisplayFormulaWithMatrices (line 4)
displayFormula("c=b*a", a, [[1 2];[3 4]])
```

I am pretty sure the following code proves displayFormula() is buggy with matrices:

```
syms a b c d A Z
A = [[a b];[c d]]
a1 = 2;
mix = subs(A, a, a1)
Z = A*A
Z1 = subs(A*A,a,a1)
displayFormula('Z = A*A')
displayFormula("Z = A*A", a, a1)
```

The above code produces the following livescript output:

[image: livescript output]

The 'Z1=' livescript result installs '2' into the display. displayFormula("A*A") cannot install values into the variables. The verbose form of displayFormula("A*A", a, a1) not only fails to install '2' into the display but also collapses the display completely.

One other thing we know for certain is that displayFormula() does not function as shown in the [Apple documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/displayformula.html). Apple documentation identifies the argument of displayForumula() as a 'symstr'. But this code works fine when the argument of displayForumula() is not a symstr:

```
A=[[1 2];[1 4]]
displayFormula("A*A")
```

So my conclusion is that displayFormula() will be improved to work better with matrices, but its buggy now.

Comment: I think it is because otherwise ambiguity in the syntax would happen. You should be able to do `syms a b c; displayFormula(symstr,[a b c],[2 3 -1])`, meaning every element of the 3rd input corresponds to an element of the second input. If you also allow the third input to be matrices, then there is no input parsing possible and likely there are weird cases where you don't know how to assign the values well. I think its a design decision to avoid that, albeit I completely see how it can be confusing.

Comment: Ander, I think you could be right but I think more likely that the verbose form displayFormula() has not been coded to accept matrices as arguments. The verbose form will accept Ints and Doubles so there is some overloading of the argument permitted. In any event, the argument is not restricted to a symstr  as shown in the Apple Documentation.